# Combining Imputed Datasets to make a single prediction — probability— for each example using a Classifier

Tags: r, classification, predict, combinators, imputation

I am working with a large dataset --300,000 records-- which has many missing values. So I used Imputation to fill the missing values and more specifically the Chained-Equations Multiple Imputation method. In particular, I used three R packages to get a better feeling of their relative performance: Mice, Mi and MissForest. The imputation functions return imputation object from which I can extract the datasets. I have 10 datasets from each imputation function. My question is how to use them to run a Classifier and then use the model to Predict probabilities for the examples in my dataset.

One approach I used was to split the imputed datasets into training and testing subsets, then train a separate model --using a Classifier-- on each training dataset (e.g. 10 training datasets -> 10 models), consequently make separate predictions (probabilities) using each model separately on the respective testing dataset and finally average the predicted probabilities to end up with a single estimate for each example.

I wonder however if my approach is theoretically sound and if there is some other preferred method to combine imputed datasets and come up with a single prediction (probability) for each example.

I also tried to use the mitools package to combine the imputed datasets.  The code was the following.

```
implst_train <- imputationList(datasets = list(compl1_Train, compl2_Train, compl3_Train, compl4_Train, compl5_Train,
                                               compl6_Train, compl7_Train, compl8_Train, compl9_Train, compl10_Train
                                               ))

models_implst<-with(implst_train, 
                    glm(NonCreditCard ~ Gender + Age + Profession + Region + YearsCustomer + Income,family=binomial()))

p <- with(implst_train, 
     predict(models_implst, type ="response"))
```

p turned out to be a list of nested lists and I could not make any sense out of it.

Finally, the with() function of mitools did not work with the MicrosoftML functions I am also using.

Your advice will be appreciated.

#

Edit

#

I plotted the probability densities separately for the Positive and Negative examples in each imputed dataset separately (10 PDFs x 2).  Then I plotted the averaged values of Probabilities across the imputed datasets and it became clear that this is definitely a wrong way to proceed.  The distinction between Positive and Negative labels became entirely blurred.

Here is the code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = compl1_Test,  aes(x = predict1_avts, fill = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.4)  + 
  # coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 100000)) + 
  geom_density(data = compl1_Test,  aes(x = predict1ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl2_Test,  aes(x = predict2ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl3_Test,  aes(x = predict3ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl4_Test,  aes(x = predict4ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl5_Test,  aes(x = predict5ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl6_Test,  aes(x = predict6ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl7_Test,  aes(x = predict7ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl8_Test,  aes(x = predict8ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl9_Test,  aes(x = predict9ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_density(data = compl10_Test,  aes(x = predict10ts, color = as.factor(NonCreditCard)), alpha = 0.5, size = 1)
```

And this is the graph:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but it sounds like your aim is to impute the missing values in your dataset with multiple imputations averaged.  I can't speak for Mi and mice, but I'm pretty sure that missForest is inherently a multiple-imputation method because it imputes the dataset multiple times before stopping criteria is met.

Comment: Yes they all are multiple imputation methods. However, this is the first time I am using this method and I am still researching the best method to take advantage of these datasets to conduct classification.  In the end of the day I must assign to each example in the test dataset a probability and a label and I am unsure how to do it.  This is the motivation behind my question.

Comment: Okay, well missing value imputation and classification are two related, but completely different problems. You may want to rephrase your question to indicate that you are trying to perform classification.  Also:  include sample data, include the dimensions of your dataset, include some info on what type of classification it is (i.e. is it binary classification, or multi-class classification, etc.).  Maybe also research "Cross-validation"  and take a look at some questions on stats.stackexchange.com, they have lots of info on statistical learning methods.

Comment: Typically with MI, you conduct the same analysis across each imputed dataset and then average the resulting outcome across datasets. This is intended to average out the uncertainty from missingness... In this case, you'd average your predicted probabilities across datasets. You wouldn't split the datasets into test/train s.t. some are test and some are train.... **example data would make this question stronger.**